# Convert String to Time

Tags: php, time, datetime-format, data-conversion

I am trying to convert string to time,
the string i have are in this format,
"1 hr", "1hour", "2 hr 30 mins", "3 hour 45 minutes"

I want to convert them into H:i:s format. so it appears such as 3:45:00

currently i am using str_pos to get characters before hr and strip them and join them to form h:i:s format.

```
$data = strtolower($data);
$hours = '00';
$minutes = '00';
$seconds = '00';

$pos = strpos($data, "h");
if ($pos !== false) {
    $hours = str_replace([' ', ':', ','], '', substr($data, 0, $pos));
    $data = str_replace(['hours', 'hour', 'hrs', 'hr'], '', substr($data, $pos));
}

$pos = strpos($data, "m");
if ($pos !== false) {
    $minutes = str_replace([' ', ':', ','], '', substr($data, 0, $pos));
    $data = str_replace(['minutes', 'minute', 'mins', 'min'], '', substr($data, $pos));
}

$pos = strpos($data, "s");
if ($pos !== false) {
    $seconds = str_replace([' ', ':', ','], '', substr($data, 0, $pos));
}

return $hours . ':' . $minutes . ':' . $seconds;
```

similarly to minutes....

Any better and easy way to do this? Is there anyway i can use DateTime methods?

Comment: https://eval.in/681782   . is this what you want?

Comment: Not nice, but should work: `$string = '3 hour 45 minutes';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'h \h\o\ur i \m\i\n\u\t\e\s', $string );
var_dump( $dateTime->format( 'H:i:s' ) );`

Comment: Abhishek Salian   check the comments and answers and let us know

Comment: works for hrs and mins but not only hrs or only mins

Comment: @swidmann updated my code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = str_replace(['hr', 'mins'], ['hours', 'minutes'], $string);

$dateTime = new DateTime('midnight');
$dateTime->modify('+' . $time);

var_dump($dateTime->format('H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex ?

```
<?php
$s = "3 hr 45 minutes";

preg_match("#([0-9]+)[ hour]+ ([0-9]+)[ minutes]+#", $s, $m);

echo "$m[1]:$m[2]:00";

?>
```

Comment: if string format will change then i am afraid that it will not work

Comment: yeah works with say "1 hr 10 mins" but if i pass "1 hr"  or "10 mins" it doesnt work